# Why is the output of this regex different across g++ and vc++?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, g++

Below is a very simple C++ regex program

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    regex re( "^([^\\.]+\\.?)+$" , regex::icase);
    smatch match;

    if (regex_search(string("abcd.com") , match, re) ) 
        cout<<"Match Found";
    else
        cout<<"Not Found";

    return 0;
}
```

VC++ 2010 says "Not Found"

g++ says "Match Found"

Why?

Comment: `g++` _what_? There have been hundreds of `g++`s... Also, stop shouting please.

Comment: ^^ well, some of them work.

Comment: [vs 2013 agrees with gcc and clang](http://rextester.com/QPBOF63306) sounds like a fixed bug.

Comment: On `clang++  3.6.0` it says `MATCH FOUND` as well.

Comment: Just tested in VS2012 - `MATCH FOUND`.

Comment: Anddddd there goes my desire to help